# jqGrid load WebMethod data

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to modify this [example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Keith.htm) to invoke a webmethod with the url attribute.
How can I get the constructor to invoke the WebMethod "Test2"?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
     $(function () {
         "use strict";
         var myFloatTemplate = { width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" };

         $("#CompTable").jqGrid({
             url: "<%= AdminPath %>WebMethods/WebService1.asmx/Test2",
             datatype: "json",
             height: "auto",
             colNames: ["Part", "Description", "Src", "Std Usage", "Usage Inc Scrap", "Rate Scrap", "UOM", "Item", "Unit Cost", "Stock"],
             colModel: [
                    { name: "COMP1_PART", width: 120 },
                    { name: "WSCOMPDESC", width: 300 },
                    { name: "WSCOMPSRC", width: 40 },
                    { name: "COMPUSAGE", template: myFloatTemplate },
                    { name: "WSGROSSQTY", width: 120, template: myFloatTemplate },
                    { name: "COMPRATE_SCRAP", width: 90, template: myFloatTemplate },
                    { name: "COMPBASIC_UNIT", width: 60 },
                    { name: "COMP1_ITEM", width: 60 },
                    { name: "WSCOMPUNITCOST", template: myFloatTemplate },
                    { name: "WSCOMPQTYSTOCK", template: myFloatTemplate }
                ],
             jsonReader: {
                 repeatitems: false,
                 id: "ID"
             },
             caption: "Bom Detail",
             rowNum: 10000,
             autoencode: true,
             loadonce: true,
             sortable: true,
             loadComplete: function () {
                 var $self = $(this);
                 if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
                     setTimeout(function () {
                         $(this).trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
                     }, 50);
                 }
             }
         });
     });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

and

```cs
[DataContract]
public class JJ
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID;
      [DataMember]
    public string WSCOMPDESC;
      [DataMember]
    public string WSCOMPUNITCOST;
      [DataMember]
      public string WSCOMPSRC;
      [DataMember]
    public int WSCOMPQTYSTOCK;
      [DataMember]
    public string COMPBASIC_UNIT;
      [DataMember]
    public float COMPUSAGE;
      [DataMember]
    public int COMPRATE_SCRAP;
      [DataMember]
    public float  WSGROSSQTY;
      [DataMember]
    public string COMP1_PART;
      [DataMember]
    public string COMP1_ITEM;


}
[DataContract]
public class MM
{
    [DataMember]
    public int total;
    [DataMember]

    public int page;
    [DataMember]
    public int records;
    [DataMember]
    public List<JJ> rows;
}


[WebMethod]
public MM Test2()
{
    MM m = new MM();
    m.records = 2;
    m.page = 1;
    m.total = 1;

    m.rows = new List<JJ>();

    m.rows.Add(new JJ() { COMP1_ITEM = "1", WSCOMPDESC = "A"}); 
    m.rows.Add(new JJ() { COMP1_ITEM = "2", WSCOMPDESC = "B"});

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't implemented server side paging of data you should return all data. the simplest format will be array of items. So you can modify the code of the `WebMethod` `Test2` to the following:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public object Test2 () {
    return new[] {
        new { COMP1_ITEM = "1", WSCOMPDESC = "A"},
        new { COMP1_ITEM = "2", WSCOMPDESC = "B"}
    };
}
```

Then you should use `ajaxGridOptions` option of jqGrid to set `contentType` to `"application/json;"` or `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` and use `mtype: "POST"` if you don't use any other attributes of the WebMethod.

The last important thing is the following: ASMX wraps the returned results to `d` property. So the returned data looks like

```json
{"d":[{"COMP1_ITEM":"1","WSCOMPDESC":"A"},{"COMP1_ITEM":"2","WSCOMPDESC":"B"}]}
```

instead of

```json
[{"COMP1_ITEM":"1","WSCOMPDESC":"A"},{"COMP1_ITEM":"2","WSCOMPDESC":"B"}]
```

So one should use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d" }` to read the data. The final remark: you can use `postData: ""` to remove sending of all unneeded parameters by jqGrid.

See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ObjectWebMethodForJqGrid.zip) the demo project.